# The custom reject reason box goes outside the popup in suggested edit review in Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, review, design, meta, rejection-reasons

The custom reject reason box goes outside the popup in suggested edit review. See here.

[image]

Can we fix this? Please.

Comment: Lots of CSS fail today.

Comment: Still the same problem....

Comment: This is [still happening](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2988645#2988645).

Comment: This is [still happening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247990/266359).

Comment: MSE is full with design bugs to this day, and none is getting fixed. Probably all designers are too busy working on new sites to be launched and the "ordinary" devs don't want to touch the CSS. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed, perhaps when this dialog was changed to use [Stacks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313846/295232), or perhaps earlier already.

[image]