# Text box for rejecting edit is too big!

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

I just [reviewed an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/36345), and rejected it for "no improvement whatsoever."

When I hit the "reject" button, I noticed that the text box for entering a custom reject reason is wider than the whole reject box:

[image: ""]

This was seen today in Chrome 40.0.2214.93 (*and thank you for making me check the version, I'm currently updating my browser*)

I believe this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: @Loong You are correct. I searched for it but couldn't find it -- I guess you'r just better at it than I am ;-) ....thanks!